# MetaMask: ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code

Tags: transactions, metamask, drizzle, ganache-cli

I'm working with ganache, drizzle and Vue on a decentralized app.

I have a simple contract IPFSStore which contains the following function:

```
 function changeStatus(address owner, string memory _fileHash) public{
      File[] memory files = filesArray[owner];
      for(uint i=0; i<files.length; i++){
           if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked((files[i].hashedID))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((_fileHash)))){
             filesArray[owner][i].shortDescription = "Pending";
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call this function from an another contract like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
import "./IPFSStore.sol";

contract ReviewRequest {
  IPFSStore ipfs;
 function addRequest(address contractAddress, string memory _fileHash) public{
      address my = msg.sender;
      ipfs = IPFSStore(contractAddress);
      ipfs.changeStatus(my, _fileHash);
}
```

However, in MetaMask I get the "ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code." error and after paying gas, transaction is unsuccessful.

Commenting out the `ipfs.changeStatus(my, _fileHash);` line prevents the MetaMask error, so I presume that I call the external function incorrectly.

How should I call the function of another contract to not get the error?

Comment: There's not enough information. What are `filesArray`, `IPFSStore`? Is `contractAddress` a valid contract?

Comment: The function works fine, the problem is when calling it from another contract @Ismael

Comment: I can't reproduce without the contracts. I don't see an explicit problem with the code posted. Some things that might fail: contractAddress is not a valid contract, not enough gas, deployed code is different.